# how to call js function without defined in native side

Tags: react-native

I notice from [calling-react-native-functions-from-native-events](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.40/docs/communication-ios.html#calling-react-native-functions-from-native-events) that I could call js function or event with defined prop in native side

`RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(onChange, RCTBubblingEventBlock)`

but how could I call js function without any defined in native side?

for example, if I wrap my project as sdk which be embedded in others'app, and I want to dynamic add new method in js side without modify any sdk native code, so the app will directly call changed logic without update sdk package framework after hotfix.

how should I implement it?

thanks for your time,

regards.

Comment: Is your sdk a component or just a  standard library ?

Comment: @AshikVetrivelu  thanks for your reply, my sdk is framework which include ui component and interface which could be called directly by app, and I want to find the appropriate way to move all logic to js side.

Comment: If you want to call a function through your component, then set a callback to the function in your component as a prop.